# Side by Side HTML tables inside an overflow

Tags: html, css

I have an popup that will be displaying two different tables. Different users will see different options (table rows) so I needed two independent tables that look like one. The options will get complicated so it would be best to use two tables.

Both tables will be displayed inside an overlay so space is limited and they will need to be inside an overflow.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8h5axkbj/1/

The blue table is the one that need to the right of the white table. I've tried floats and inline-blocks but I feel like I'm missing something.

```
<div id="popUpTableWrap">
<table class="table fl">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Daily Hours</th>
        <th><div class="dayTimeWidth">Sun</div></th>
        <th><div class="dayTimeWidth">Mon</div></th>
        <th><div class="dayTimeWidth">Tues</div></th>
        <th><div class="dayTimeWidth">Wed</div></th>
        <th><div class="dayTimeWidth">Thu</div></th>
        <th><div class="dayTimeWidth">Fri</div></th>
        <th><div class="dayTimeWidth">Sat</div></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Coverage Start</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Break Start</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Break End</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Coverage End</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Reaction</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Resolution</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Critical - React</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Critical - Resolve</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Urgent - Resolve</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Urgent - Resolve</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-input" value="00:00"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="table fl">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="nbd-title" colspan="2">Next Business Day</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="nbd">NBD</td>
        <td class="nbd">
            <select>
                <option>Y</option>
                <option>N</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nbd">NBD Critical</td>
        <td class="nbd">
            <select>
                <option>Y</option>
                <option>N</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nbd">NBD Urgent</td>
        <td class="nbd">
            <select>
                <option>Y</option>
                <option>N</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nbd">NBD Non-Urgent</td>
        <td class="nbd">
            <select>
                <option>Y</option>
                <option>N</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nbd">NBD Appointment</td>
        <td class="nbd">
            <select>
                <option>Y</option>
                <option>N</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nbd">NBD Exception A</td>
        <td class="nbd">
            <select>
                <option>Y</option>
                <option>N</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nbd">NBD Exception B</td>
        <td class="nbd">
            <select>
                <option>Y</option>
                <option>N</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nbd">Severity</td>
        <td class="nbd">XXXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nbd">Holiday Coverage</td>
        <td class="nbd">
            <select>
                <option>Y</option>
                <option>N</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nbd">Business Process</td>
        <td class="nbd">XXXX</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: each table should be inside a div and then you can align like this:  
  
.table_left     { float:left; display:block; width:calc(100% - 145px); }  
.table_right     { float:left; display:block; width:145px; }  
  
(145px is the blue table with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty much code in there..

i updated your code and added a few lines of css and two classes to `table`

```
.table1 {
    width: 80%;
}

.table2 {
    width: 20%;
}

.fl {
    float: left;
}
.table {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

here is your fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8h5axkbj/7/

Comment: This is pretty much right except I needed to wrap the tables in a div first and set a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting both tables to display as `inline-block`.

```
table.one {width:650px; display:inline-block;}
table.two {width:150px; display:inline-block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8h5axkbj/6/

You will need to make sure that both tables have the same number of rows or they will not be aligned correctly.

Comment: This will not work because the tables will be inside an overflow. The popup window I will be using is only around 575px.

Answer (score 0):

```
Float left for both tables helps to align tables properly.
```

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/8h5axkbj/5/embedded/result/)

Comment: It needs to be inside an overflow.

Comment: As per provided html, both tables placed inside an overflow div(#popup-coverages-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

typo.. the classes in CSS are '`fll`' and '`flr`'.
Changing '`fl`' and '`fr`' in the html to these classes will fix this.

http://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/8h5axkbj/8/